# Search for a value in a column wise sorted array in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

How can I search for a value in a column-wise sorted array in linear time O(n)?

I need to write a function that takes in a column-wise sorted 2d array, and returns true if a specified value is in the array.

Example of a column-wise sorted array

```
int[][] m = {
      {1, 2, 3},
      {4, 6, 5},
      {8, 10, 9}
    };
```

How can I solve this problem in linear time O(n)?

Comment: _"solve this problem in linear time O(n)"_. What is `n`? Number of rows, columns or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the array is sorted column wise we can visit all the columns to find the target element. Suppose there are N columns in worst case scenario we have to visit all the columns and we have to search for the element across M rows for each of these.

Since the matrix is sorted col wise we could do search in log(M) - leading to N*log(M) worst case time complexity.

But if you meant O(n) as N elements of col then we should think to optimize more.

Comment: In the answer itself you've stated that your approach doesn't meet the desired complexity. Why have you added this as an answer then?

Comment: I think you had the same doubt too what does O(n) mean. I just contributed what I know. For row wise and col wise sorted matrix there is a possible way to get the element by O(N+M) but I think for a col wise sorted matrix and no sort for row wise then it might cost N*log(M).